# UISplitViewController remove button on top left in master controller iPadOS 14

Tags: ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, ios14

In my app I use a lot of UISplitViewController. I update my iPad to iPadOS 14, now when the device shows an UISplitViewController it shows me a button in top left corner of master controller. Here's the image to understand what happen:
[image]
There's a way to remove this button? I'm not interested to collapse the detail controller.
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to set the `UISplitViewControllers`'s `presentsWithGesture` instance property to `false`.

From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller/1623171-presentswithgesture):

> When this property is false, the split view controller doesn’t install a gesture recognizer for changing the display mode. The split view controller also doesn’t display a button to change the display mode.

You may also need to set `preferredSplitBehavior` to `.tile` and `preferredDisplayMode` to `.oneBesideSecondary`.